# Is it possible to use azure to release a core 3.1 app with different environment variables?

Tags: azure, .net-core-3.1

I have different appsettings files (Development, Production Staging) for a core 3.1 api I am building.

Different appsettings have different parameters appropriate for each environment.

In Visual Studio, I can switch easily between these via the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

But what I need to do is deploy it via azure to IIS.  It will run in IIS as an application attached to a website.

All I want to do, is create in Azure, different release steps to release different versions of my api with different environment variables set.  There is almost no other difference in my deployment pipeline stages otherwise.

One thing I've tried is adding the environment variable into `Web.Config`, however, this means I can't change that value.  I.E, if I set that value to be:

`<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />`

Then all my pipeline stages use that value rather than allowing me to set a value for each stage (development, production, staging, are all development).

How do I have a different value for that environment variable each stage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use deployment slots, which is specifically intended for this scenario.
Settings can be specified per deployment slot whereby they are retained for that context, even when the source is swapped into a different deployment slot.

Swapped settings:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped

How to add a slot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#add-a-slot